# Is it posible to implement 2 functions for the same event handler in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to Javascript or JQuery. I have a quite complete HTML resource, in which a button element has a function X1 to handle its click event.

Now, I don't want to modify any thing from the existing HTML resource, but want to add my function X2 when the user clicks on the button. My purpose is after functionX1 is implemented, my functionX2 will be implemented.

I wrote functionX2 in a separate javascript file, and include in the index.html.

Is it posible?

--------------------------------  EDIT ---------------------------------

The existing html resource looks like follow:

- "libs.js" that contains functionX1 to handle the click event:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   //-do X1 here
   ....

}
```

- "index.html" that contains a button

```
head

script src="libs.js"

/head

body

div id="button"

/body
```

Now, I don't want to modify anything from "libs.js", I write a separate javascript file "mylibs.js", in which create another function to handle the button's click event.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   //-do X2 here
   ....

}
```

In the index.html, I include my js file

```
head

script src="libs.js"
script src="mylibs.js"

/head

body

div id="button"

/body
```

So does it serve my purpose: do X1 and then do X2 when the button is clicked?

If I include as above, when the button gets clicked, one of the following cases will happen?

- X1 will be implemented, X2 is ignored.
- X1 will be ignored, X2 will be implemented.
- X1 will be implemented, and the X2 will be implemented.

Comment: wait? but this is already supported by default, doesn't it? as far as I remember `on()` uses `addEventListener()`/`attachEvent()` which allow multiple handlers for the same event

Comment: @Stefan, you're absolutely right. Sometimes the obvious isn't that obvious :-) I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#my-btn").on("click", function () { alert(1); });
$("#my-btn").on("click", function () { alert(2); });
```

This is already supported in jQuery.

Comment: So with this code, alert(1) and alert(2) will be implemented in order? Thanks Stefan.

Comment: "Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound" (jQuery docs), so as long as you attach your handler after your library does, it should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

This is easily possible. Dependent on how the code is structured you would just need to place the call to your `functionX2` after the call to `functionX1` in the anonymous handler:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    functionX1();
    functionX2();
});
```

Alternatively, you can call `functionX2()` at the end of `functionX1()`:

```
var functionX1 = function() {
    // your logic...

   functionX2();
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to modify any existing javascript library. I write my own javascript, and include in html file. If you understand what I mean. Probably, I need to update my post.

Comment: Then you would probably have to use some hacky method of forcing the order of assigned events. Why can you not modify the existing code?

Comment: It's a third party library, can be updated when necessary. So that's why I don't want to modify anything from this js file.

Comment: Does it have any callback parameters you can use to hook to?

Comment: No, they don't have any callback parameters I can use to hook to. They don't know that I need to implement additional thing.

Answer (score 1):

[**edit**]
As Stefan correctly stated: jQuery can handle multiple eventhandlers and fires them in the order they are bound.

So just add

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
   X2();
});
```

**after** the original handler was attached, and you'll be ok.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chmpvb0y/4/)

---

**[I'll leave this for future reference, but it's obsolete**]

There is an option, but it is hack, prone to errors and I would recommend Rory's first solution, but here we go:

```
//the original click
$('#foo').click(function () {
   X1();
});

//add an additional MOUSEUP listener
//note that mouseup fires before click, so there has to be a timeout
$('#foo').mouseup(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        X2()
    }, 200);
});

function X1() {
    //run X1
}

function X2() {
   //run X2
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chmpvb0y/2/)